# Same rectangle drawn despite different array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas

I have a tile array which looks like so:

```
var gameCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = gameCanvas.getContext("2d");

var mapArray = [
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,0,0,0]
];
```

and a loop which draws tiles to the canvas from that map

```
var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;

for(i=0; i < mapArray.length; i++){
    for(j=0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++){
        if(mapArray[i][j] == 1){
            ctx.rect(posX, posY, 32, 32);
            ctx.fillStyle="black";
        }
        if(mapArray[i][j] == 2){
            ctx.rect(posX, posY, 32, 32);
            ctx.fillStyle="red";
        }
        if(mapArray[i][j] == 3){
            ctx.rect(posX, posY, 32, 32);
            ctx.fillStyle="blue";
        }
        ctx.fill();
        posX += 32;     
    }
    posX = 0;
    posY +=32;  
}
```

Every '1' in the array is displayed as a black square as expected. 
The problem is, every '2' and '3' are also displayed as a black square despite the declaration of a different colour in the `fillStyle` of that if statement.

When logged, each if statement returns the value (1,2 or 3) as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`ctx.beginPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath) and [`ctx.stroke()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/stroke) as nesting commands.

```js
var gameCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = gameCanvas.getContext("2d"),
    mapArray = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,0,0,0]],
    posX = 0,
    posY = 0,
    i, j;

for (i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++){
    posX = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {
        if (mapArray[i][j]) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(posX, posY, 32, 32);
            ctx.fillStyle = ["black", "red", "blue"][mapArray[i][j] - 1];
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        posX += 32;     
    }
    posY += 32;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

Comment: So use beginPath to seperate the rects, otherwise they are considered part of the same shape. Good to know. Thanks, this was helpful.